# Editor does not become active when file is selected in project explorer

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have Project Explorer view. I have few files that are open:[image: InitiallyLoadedFiles]

Then if I close the application and reopen it I have the same image as above, but the problem comes when I want to open one of the files from the Project Explorer view again. Lets say I want to open FileTwo.java again. I end up with this:
[image: AfterCloseAndReopen]

Tha happens only after the application is relaunched (for every file that has been oppened). As you can see in the first picture FileThree.java was open. On relaunch it is selected and has link with the Project Explorer view and it doesn't open it twice. Once a file is oppened again the link between Project Explorer view and the editor is avaiable again but I still have them twice in the editor.

What am I missing to implement?

Comment: Is this your own RCP? Project Explorer requires all sorts of things to be properly initialized by the RCP.

Comment: Yes, it's my own. The example is from eclipse just to show it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of issue once, the problem was that sometimes files were opened using their URI, et sometimes directly with the IResource. 
So when I tried to open a file twice with the two methods, two editors were opened.

You can easily check if it's your problem by checking the path of the editor resource, just let the cursor on the editor and the path will be displayed. In my case paths were different for the same file.

If this is your issue then you have to standardise the way you open your file, from your explorer and when your application starts.

Hope this help